# Bubblesort generalization

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, sorting

I was comparing and analyzing the sort algorithms thereby came across a  machine which took 200 secs to sort 200 names but to generalize, in 800 secs wouldn't it sort 800 names?

Comment: I can't tell what you are asking.  What kind of sorting algorithm?  The answer depends on the sorting algorithm.  Second, there's no way any reasonable sorting algorithm will take 200 seconds to sort 200 names; it should be vastly faster than that.  Third, what research and self-study have you done?  What reading have you done?  I expect you to do a significant amount of research and self-study before asking.

Answer (score 1):

Two main points: First of all, you fell in the "trap of universal linearity" (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/630339/pedagogy-how-to-cure-students-of-the-law-of-universal-linearity) for other manifestations of the trap). If you double the input, the computation time only doubles *if your algorithm takes linear time*. Sorting with [Radix Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) actually takes linear time, so in that case it would be correct to simply double the time. You never explicitly stated how you sort (which you should, otherwise how should we answer your question?), but your *Bubblesort* appearance in the title lets me assume that it's Bubblesort-related.
Which brings me to the second point: What could that $O(n²)$ that is probably mentioned somewhere in your literature have to do with your question?